# get the html text by executing url

Tags: .net

We used chilkatdotnet.dll to do this. The dll has a function called GetEmail(url) that will execute the url and return the html text that is rendered by the url. for example if we say GetEmail('www.stackoverflow.com') it will return the html text same as the one that we get when we click on view source. We are trying to implement the same functionality using .NET 2.0.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Comment: looks like someone has some function naming issues...

Comment: What do you mean by 'execute the url'?  Does it send an email?

Answer (score 11):

Isn't this all you want?

```
string s = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am looking for except one minor issue. If the page has images then it should convert it into bytes or something and embed it in the string. what I am trying to do is set the result of this as the email body so that the images will also be displayed as inline content.

Comment: There's no class in the .NET framework that does this. You should search for a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTPWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) is probably something you'd want to look at; especially the [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method. Examples are provided on the `GetResponse` documentation page.